# Return Value of Metric if Hasn't Changed in 30 Minutes

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a metric that holds the completed percentage of a running process. I'm trying to build a query that returns the value of the percentage if it hasn't changed in x minutes. I tried to use `changes(progress_percent[30m])==0` but that returns the number of changes, not the metric value. I want to know if the process is stuck on some percentage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the a [AND or UNLESS](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) binary operator. Taking `AND`:

> vector1 and vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of vector1
> for which there are elements in vector2 with exactly matching label sets.
> Other elements are dropped.

In your case:

```
progress_percent AND changes(progress_percent[30m]) == 0
```

It will return `change` only if there are no changes for the last 30min.

Comment: I think you meant `progress_percent AND changes(progress_percent[30m] == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MichaelDoubez. Using your lead, I used this at the end:

`0 < progress_percent < 1 AND changes(progress_percent[30m]) == 0`

This way I get the metric value from the left-hand side vector as per documentation:

> The metric name and values are carried over from the left-hand side vector.

and make sure there were no changes from the right-hand side vector.